# Why I am getting the unselected data adding into my database?

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to insert multiple data that has only been selected checkbox. But Unfortunately, It also inserted the the unselected checkbox and also getting duplicate data.

Here's the UI for selecting data.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
if(isset($check)){

$client = $_POST['client'];
$project = $_POST['project'];
$kit_no = $_POST['kit_no']; //array
$kit_desc = $_POST['kit_desc']; //array

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($check);$i++){
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($kit_no);$i++){
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($kit_desc);$i++){

$query=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tbltrainsets_kit(id, client, project, kit_no, kit_desc)VALUES(
    '',                      
    '".$client."',
    '".$project."',
    '".$kit_no[$i]."',
    '".$kit_desc[$i]."'
    )")or die(mysqli_error($con));          
} 
} 
}

}
```

The output that I produce is like this: (Please see the actual pix below):

[image]

The unselected data ('NA') was inserted into the database. It should only be the item 'DTR4000037253' inserting into the database.

Thank you in advace. Please respect my questions. I'm still studying do please do not bash. :|

Comment: What is `$check`? I assume it's a collection of both checkboxes? You really need to run an `isset()` against each checkbox individually. If it's an array of the checkboxes (such as `name=actions[]`, you can use `if(isset($_POST['actions']) && in_array(...`.

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['checkboxName']) && $_POST['checkboxName']=='CheckboxValue'){ /*The checkbox is selected*/ }`

Comment: You're using the same variable `$i` for all of your `for` loops. And you have no check in the for loop as to whether `$check[$i]` is set or not.

Comment: I am still getting the same error and duplicate data. I've already changed the variable. Can someone shome me the correct code for this? please help.... Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution for this. When I study my code I realized that all of the logic is wrong.

Here's my code:

```
if(isset($check)){ // verify if checkbox is checked
foreach($check as $selected){ // select each checkbox that was selected an

 // select value from the column equal to the ID of the selected checkbox
$kit_no = $this->dbquery->modGetdynamicval('tblkit','id', $selected, 'kit_no');   
$kit_desc = $this->dbquery->modGetdynamicval('tblkit','id', $selected, 'kit_desc');



$query=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tbltrainsets_kit(id, client, project, kit_no, kit_desc)
VALUES('',  '".$client."','".$project."','".$kit_no."','".$kit_desc."')")or die(mysqli_error($con));

echo $selected."</br>";
echo $kit_no."</br>";
echo $kit_desc."</br>";

}//end for loop
```

I'm using CI framework for getting the value the other 2 variables that I want to insert.